# Edit bower packages

Tags: bower

I've recently started using Bower and something I cannot figure out is what would be the correct way of editing a package? For example I use SwiperJS but a lot of the CSS that it comes with just isn't relevant for my output so I've been commenting it out so when it's compiled with SASS it gets removed. I've been doing this without Bower.

If I was to install SwiperJS using Bower instead, what would be the best way to do the same thing? I assume just ending the files in the bower_components directory isn't best.

Also I'm just using SwiperJS as an example here.